# I have a problem with C++ because it refuses to display the answer and I don't know where the problem is in code

Tags: c++

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <tchar.h> using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
    double x;
    for (x = 2; x < 6.3; x + 0.4);
    {
        double Rez, Rez1;
        Rez = pow(x, 4) + 2 * pow(x, 2) + 3;
        Rez1 = cos(3 * x) + exp(-2 * x);
        cout << Rez << Rez1;
    }
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
```

it supposed to count equations with each value of X in the range from 2 to 6.3, with a step of 0.4
aka 2, 2.4, 2.8, etc.

Comment: And what does it do instead? Is there an error message?

Comment: I highly recommend [enabling more warnings](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6YhT3zT8M) if you're not seeing any.

Comment: If instead of "x + 0.4)" I type += it shows "1762.640.939223". It's...*too* big of a number than I need, but here it doesn't even show the errors, just no output.

Comment: `x + 0.4` does not modify `x`, so `x < 6.3` will remain true forever and your loop will never terminate. Perhaps you should also print a space between your two outputs so they are easier to read.

Comment: The reason for enabling more warnings is that a compiler can tell you that `for (x = 2; x < 6.3; x + 0.4);` is probably a mistake (final semicolon creates an empty block and means your indented block is not controlled by the loop).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the final semicolon as someone in the comments suggested. Just due to that semicolon, x's value was incremented above 6.4 in the 1st iteration and only 1 iteration was taking place. Also the variable x needs to be incremented in an appropriate way!
Here is the working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <tchar.h> 
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) 
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
     double x=2;
    for ( x = 2 ; x < 6.3;  x = x + 0.4 )
    {
        double Rez, Rez1;
        Rez = pow( x, 4) + 2 * pow( x, 2) + 3;
        Rez1 = cos(3 * x) + exp(-2 * x);
        cout <<"Result 1:" <<Rez <<"  Result 2:"<< Rez1<< endl;
    }

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```